# How to make Tab Bar Item disabled and how to change color and transparency for disabled Item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, uitabbar

Is there a way to make chosen Tab Bar Item look disabled programmatically?

I have Tab Bar, almost everywhere its Items look active (it is delete, edit, search buttons). But on some pages some of its Items has to be inactive, showing user that he can't edit/delete anything here. I'm thinking, is there a way to change the visual appearance of chosen Tab Bar Item? Or better to use just set of the Buttons?

[all active items/buttons in a bar, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cloOK.png)

[all active items/buttons in the bar, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHaum.png)

UPD: Desigion for disabling Item found, but when I make the Item disabled, I need to change its colour. Now it has the same color as `UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor` but with transparency. Is there a way to change color and transparency for disabled Item (make it coloured differently and not transparent), keeping the colour for unselected Items?

Answer (score 1):

For required tabbar item try to set `false` for `.enabled` property.

*Obj-C*

```
.enabled = NO;
```

*Swift*

```
.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: I'm changing the colours of active and inactive elements of Tab Bar in `AppDelegate.swift `UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
  UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.black` and then in my UIViewController I do this
`self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].isEnabled = true
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![2].isEnabled = false` but nothing changes in colours

Comment: Found the way, just needed to use an outlet for Tab Bar. Thank you!

Comment: UITabBarItem has no `userInteractionEnabled` property.

Comment: Yes, it hasn't, so only .isEnabled fits the case.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could make your `tabBar` dynamic and instead of disabling/enabling, only *show* the relevant items. This way, the items are always nicely displayed and you don't have any gaps as you have in your screenshot.

Comment: I really would love to have all the items on its places all the time, just change the activity and colors of it.